# Tenor drum sweeps exercises

Tags: practice, drums, percussion

Hey does anyone here know any really good excercizes for practicing sweep patterns for marching tenor drums (preferably with 6 drums)? I have little to do with school shutdown and just wanted to improve. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

*(I actually wanted to comment but my reputation is less than 50)*
Obviously, the most logical thing to do in this case is to practice! Try to play a short exercise like the one in the picture below.
[image]

Just practice, and in this case practice makes perfect. Try to practice the exercises (that you find online, of course) with increasing tempo, but always make sure your current tempo is clean and accurate.